# Is Malthael the Angel of Wisdom?

Tags: diablo-iii

During the Expansion, Reaper of Souls, I notice Malthael takes on as Death. However, in previous games and the current one; especially in certain Lore Books and talking to Imperious Archangel of Valor, he is referred to as the Archangel of Wisdom. Does he keep his Aspect of Wisdom, or did he change that before his defeat in Pandemonium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing to indicate that he lost his place as the Archangel of Wisdom when he became the Angel of Death. In fact (speculation ahead) it could have been his knowledge that drove him to his new path.

However, he was never replaced by a new Archangel of Wisdom, and the fact that he is still referred to as the Archangel of Wisdom *as well* as the Angel of Death indicate that he still holds the title *officially*.

The only hint that this might not be the case is that after he was banished, Tyreal has been referred to as the "*Aspect* of Wisdom" after the events of Reaper of Souls. ([Source](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Storm_of_Light))

Comment: Wasn't Tyrael's new role introduced in the ending cinematic to act 4?  The original pre-RoS ending?

Comment: @Troyen It's a technicality I think... I mean yeah, he's accepted back into heaven, but he's still a mortal. So... I'm not too sure where it stands.

Comment: You source mention `taking place two months after the events of Diablo III.` SO I guess it's before Reaper of Souls. Your source mention this too : `Tyrael struggles with his position as the new Aspect of Wisdom`.  And @Troyen is right, in the end cinematic of pre-RoS, Tyrael mention the he is now accepted back into heaven, not as justice but as Wisdom.

Comment: There is also some Act I babbling prophet in New Tristram that will mention something about Justice being lost and Wisdom returning when the Prime Evils are destroyed.  It's pretty subtle though.

Comment: @BlackVegetable [Foreshadowing...](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/af/af6586221d8262d02fca8c156cc7d4269338991d649393a072520fd6466b9856.jpg)